# ICAST: Integral division result cast to double or float

Tags: java, casting

When i run sonar in my code i got following ICAST: Integral division result cast to double or float

```
float halfCanvasWidth = canvas.getWidth() / 2f;
```

canvas.getWidth() is integer How do i cast this properly

Comment: do you want to cast `canvas.getWidth()` to **float**?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cast `canvas.getWidth()` to float in java. try this:

```
float halfCanvasWidth = (float)canvas.getWidth() / 2f;
```

Comment: I have tried this Sonar will still shows the error 
This is the description 
ICAST_IDIV_CAST_TO_DOUBLE

  Description

This code casts the result of an integer division operation to double or float. Doing division on integers truncates the result to the integer value closest to zero. The fact that the result was cast to double suggests that this precision should have been retained. What was probably meant was to cast one or both of the operands to double before performing the division.

Comment: then try this `float halfCanvasWidth = ((float)canvas.getWidth()) / 2f;`